# jquery asp.net checkboxlist get item value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to get the values from checkboxlist in jquery and depending from which value there is, make the checkbox checked or unchecked. 
This is what I have:

> ```
>   <asp:CheckBoxList CssClass="styled" ID="chkTestTypeEdit" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="padding:5px;" runat="server">
>        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Y/N" />
>        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Num" />
>   </asp:CheckBoxList>
> ```

Then before modal popup is open I have this piece of code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditTest", function () {                 
    var optesttype =$(this).data('optesttype');                
    var items = $('#<% = chkTestTypeEdit.ClientID %> input:checkbox');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        var val = $('#ctl00_MainContent_chkTestTypeEdit_0').val();
        var val2 = $('label[for=" + <%= chkTestTypeEdit.ClientID %> +_0 "]').text();
        if (items[i].value == optesttype) {
            items[i].checked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    $('#EditTest').modal('show');
});
```

So the optesttype will have either 1 or 2, and then I am trying to compare that agains the item[i] value but that value is always 'on'. 
I tried two methods I found on the net with var val and val2, but nothing gets selected. 
How do you guys think I need to approach this?
Thanks, Laziale

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in the following way. My ASP.NET code for the checkboxlist is as below

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkHourly" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" 
RepeatColumns="4"   RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
 <asp:ListItem Value="0">00:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="1">01:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="2">02:00 AM</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

The generated HTML will look like this below

```
<table id="ctl00_chkHourly" border="0">
<TBODY>
 <TR>
 <TD>
  <INPUT id=ctl00_chkHourly_0 name=ctl00$chkHourly$0 value="" CHECKED type=checkbox>      
  <LABEL for=ctl00_chkHourly_0>00:00 AM</LABEL></TD>
 <TD>
  <INPUT id=ctl00_chkHourly_1 name=ctl00$chkHourly$1 value="" type=checkbox>
  <LABEL for=ctl00_chkHourly_1>01:00 AM</LABEL></TD>
 <TD>
  <INPUT id=ctl00_chkHourly_2 name=ctl00$chkHourly$2 value="" type=checkbox>
  <LABEL for=ctl00_chkHourly_2>02:00 AM</LABEL>
 </TD>
  </TR>
 </TBODY>
```

Please notice that there is a label created besides each input in the table, and when a checkbox is checked, the input's value will be 'on' and what you see as an option is the label's text, in my case I needed the text, but to get the value also in a round about away, I would read the name of the individual input fields that are checked. Please see the code below that I have written to read the text selected and also the name of the input selected so that I can strip it and read the value if needed.

```
var postData = new Array();
$("[id*=chkHourly] input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
     alert($(this).next().text());
     alert($(this).next().html());
     alert($(this).attr("name"));
     postData.push($(this).next().text());
 });

 if (postData.length > 0) {
  alert("Selected Text(s): " + postData);
 } 
 else {
  alert("No item has been selected.");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
$("#demo").live("click", function () {
        var selectedValues = "";
        $("[id*=CheckBoxList1] input:checked").each(function () {
            if (selectedValues == "") {
                selectedValues = "Selected Values:\r\n\r\n";
            }
            selectedValues += $(this).val() + "\r\n";
        });
        if (selectedValues != "") {
            alert(selectedValues);
        } else {
            alert("No item has been selected.");
        }
    });
```

Check following:

[ASP.NET CheckBoxList Operations with jQuery](http://techbrij.com/checkboxlist-jquery-asp-net-operations)

2) [sample](http://jqueryfaqs.com/Questions/ASP.Net-CheckBoxList-Get-Checked-or-Selected-Items-Client-side-using-jQuery.aspx)